# how to use constant contact database

Tags: asp.net

i want to send the news letter(advertisement) for all the users whoes email address are in constant contact database.But i dont know how to use constant contact database.

please anybody tell me how to use constant contact database.

Comment: You get the user's email address out of the database and... send the email to it?

Comment: What's a "constant contact database"? Read-only?

Answer (score 1):

You just go into your Constant Contact account, go to email marketing tab, create an email first, then at the end of that it will ask you which list you want to send to. I am assuming the list is what you are calling your "database"